# Problems using the SAGA in processing framework with qgis 2.6.1 (ubuntu)

Tags: qgis, saga, qgis-processing

I've got problems using saga in the processing framework within qgis 2.6.1 and SAGA 2.1.4
To solve this problem I was obliged to correct the line 352 of the python file

'/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/algs/saga/SagaAlgorithm.py'

return 'io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM 1 -INTERPOL 0 -GRIDS "' + destFilename + '" -FILES "' + source \

Comment: Please note that gis.stackexchange is a platform to ask and answer questions. If you want to report a bug or provide a bug fix, please use the appropriate bug tracker or code repository.